# In Autocomplete bar how to click the specific value under div ul li strong

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have lot of `li` tags under `div` and `ul`. Each `li` tag consists of `strong` tag:

```
<div style="width:380px" id="autoComplete" class="suggest fl">
    <div class="sWrap">
        <div class="iconWrap">
            <span class="nLoder" style="display: none;"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" class="" id="keywords1" style="width:375px;" name="KEYWORDS">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sugCont nScroll " id="sugDrp_autoComplete" style="display: none; width: 380px;">
        <ul class="Sdrop">
            <li class="sugTouple">
                <button style="width:100%" class="Sbtn  " tabindex="-1" type="button">
                    Acc
                    <strong>ounting</strong>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="sugTouple">
                <button style="width:100%" class="Sbtn" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                    Acc
                    <strong>ounts Payable</strong>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="sugTouple">
                <button style="width:100%" class="Sbtn" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                    Acc
                    <strong>ounts Receivable</strong>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="sugTouple">
                <button style="width:100%" class="Sbtn" tabindex="-1" type="button">
                    Acc
                    <strong>ount Management</strong>
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My current code:

```java
List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='Sdrop']"));
for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
    System.out.println(option);
    if (option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
        System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

How to select the value? I am missing something, guide me to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count li then start loop and check button text here is updated code.

```
List<WebElement> optionsToSelect =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='sugDrp_autoComplete']/ul[@class='Sdrop']/li"));
for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {

   WebElement buttonObj = option.findElement(By.tagName("button"))
   if (buttonObj.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
       System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
       buttonObj .click();
       break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In optionsToSelect nothing is stored.
I checked with
System.out.println("size"+optionsToSelect.size());

Comment: I updated code, Also please make sure that your above  html code in not in any frame if there is any frame then need to select first

Comment: No it is not under any frames. Still the same result size is  "zero"

Comment: I have updated the HTML code. Few things are added in the begining

Comment: As of now directly am passing the value like **driver.findElement(By.id("keywords1")).sendKeys("Accounting");**

In that Autocomplete box I can add multiple values like Accounting,Administration,Accounts department etc.,

Comment: id="sugDrp_autoComplete" is disabled when the page is loaded.

When a keystroke event is happened, then this div tag is getting enabled.

Comment: You should add wait function to enable div, then apply code to count li

Comment: In browser I loaded the page and opened the html and waited for 5mins.
The id = "sugDrp_autoComplete is not enabled.

In the field when I type a letter 'A' the whole tag gets enabled.

Comment: The scenario is in the Naukri registration site where you can see a field called **"What are your key skills"**
You can check the HTML code also

Comment: Above your code,
When I add this code
**driver.findElement(By.id("keywords1")).sendKeys("A");**
Then only the div tag get enabled and the remaining code starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly click the button using the xpath:

```
//button[@class='Sbtn' and text()='textToSelect']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Using your mentioned xpath, the driver unable to find it.

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='Sbtn' and text()='Accounting']"}
Command duration or timeout: 231 milliseconds

Comment: It might has to do with spaces..try using normalize-space()